# Login with Launchpad account not possible anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, launchpad

For the last two days I haven't been able to login to Ask Ubuntu with my Launchpad account. When I click on the button, it disappears and only the Google and Facebook buttons are available. I have tested it with different web browsers. What's wrong, is this a general issue or just a temporary bug?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can repro this myself as well - curious note that it doesn't occur with Arqade's Steam-based login, so it seems localized to something about either Ask Ubuntu or the Launchpad login.

Comment: @GraceNote Yeah, Launchpad is the only custom provider that asks for a username rather than redirect through the usual OpenID flow. We're investigating. As a workaround, clicking "more login options" and pasting the launchpad URL (e.g. `https://launchpad.net/~username`) in the OpenID field should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry about this, I made some breaking changes to the page to fix an issue on mobile but forgot to make sure it still worked on desktop!

This is fixed as of the next build which should happen sometime in the next few hours. Thanks for the report!